# convert these strings to number

Tags: php

using php. I have the following number

```
4,564,454

454,454,454

54.54

65.43
```

I want to convert these into number for calculating. How can I do it? Right now, the type of these number is string.

Note: the comma is not a separate of a number, it is a notion to make a number nicer. I got this format from the ajax request, I cant change the format though. So, I have to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you already have, and confirm why it does not work?

Comment: (float)(4,564,454) is not 4564454. It return some strange number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$var = floatval(str_replace(",", "", "454,454,454"));
```

Comment: Changed it to `floatval` so it will work with `'54.54'` as well as `'1,234,567'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a='4,5,4';
$ab= explode(',', $a);
foreach ($ab as $b)
{
   $sum+=$b;    //perform your calculation
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: This 4,564,454 is a number. The comma just a format of a number, it is not a separate number

Comment: what output exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to remove ,(comma) from your string as below :

```
$str=str_replace(",", "", "454,454,454");
```

Then converting in numeric:

```
$int = (int)$str;
```

or

```
$int=intval($str);
```

now do your calculation using **$int** variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$str = '4,564,454';

$str2 = '454,454,454';

$str3= '54.54';

$str4= '65.43';

$sum=0;
$sum += array_sum(explode(',',$str));
$sum += array_sum(explode(',',$str2));
$sum += $str3;
$sum += $str4;
echo $sum;
```